# ¿Cómo generar el resultado $row[itemname] en la barra desplegable de opciones?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Este es el código que tengo adelantado, pero no muestra el resultado en la barra desplegable:

```
<?php
   /*
   * Código para mostrar datos dinámicamente en un combobox.
   */
   include "../../../includes/db_connect2.php";

   $consulta = mssql_query('select itemname 
       from PS_gamedefs.dbo.Items
       where type = 30 and TypeID = 250');
   $result = mssql_fetch_array($consulta);
   ?>
       <select>    
       <?php

   while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
    {
   ?>

       <option value=" <?php
    echo $row[itemname] ?> " >
       <?php
    echo $row[itemname]; ?>
       </option>

       <?php
    }

   ?>        
       </select>
       <?php
   ?>
```

Comment: La consulta te devuelve algún resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Si solo obtienes un resultado de la consulta y lo que necesitas es que se quede seleccionada entre el resto, puedes probar este código. Si lo que quieres es añadir varios resultados, la respuesta de arriba te debería servir.

```
<select value="">   
 <?php
  if ("Opcion1"==$row['itemname']) {
   echo "<option selected=\"selected\">Opcion1</option> \n";
  }else {
   echo "<option>Opcion1</option> \n";
  }
  if ("Opcion2"==$row['itemname']) {
   echo "<option selected=\"selected\">Opcion2</option> \n";
  }else {
   echo "<option>Opcion2</option> \n";
  }
 ?> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta añadir la comparación del valor que quieres mostrar a la hora de hacer la impresión de los option

```
<select>    
<?php    
  while ( $row = mssql_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>

       <option value=" <?php echo $row[itemname] ?> " <?php if($row[itemname]=="valor a mostrar"){ echo "selected=selected" } ?> ><?php echo $row[itemname]; ?></option>

<?php
 }    
?>        
</select>
```

Al meter el if, dentro del option, haces que si el valor que obtienes de la base de datos, es el valor que quieres mostrar, este sea la opción que vas a ver en el select